# Javascript to rewrite all external links on mousedown?

Tags: javascript, redirect, url-rewriting

How can i rewrite all **external links** with a single onmousedown event?

Kinda like what facebooks does with it's link shim

**Please check the original Facebook Article about the link shim**: 
http://on.fb.me/zYAq0N

**Requirements:**

- Should work for all subdomains on mainsite.com.
- Should redirect example.com to
  mainsite.com/link.cgi?u=http://example.com
- Should only redirect links not belonging to mainsite.com.

**Uses:**

This is for security of the users of a private web app, and to protect referrers.

Best to do it on the fly for good UI as pointed out in the FB article.

That's so when users hovers over some link it shows the correct link but when he clicks it, js redirects it to my.site.com/link.cgi=http://link.com

Thanks in advance

**SOLVED**: https://gist.github.com/2342509

Comment: no evil, it's to protect my users, on my web app, from external sites.

Comment: Then, just rewrite the links entirely so the user can see where they are going to be taken when they hover.  Why show them X, but take them to Y.  That's deception.

Comment: as  you can see in the FB article i linked, for good UI, on the fly my redirect will only stop my users if site is considered with malware, we are going to use the safebrowsing api from google for the endpoint:

Comment: I've tested and written code to spoof the referrer, see  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8957778/938089?what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-hide-spoof-the-referrer-in-javascript). It was done by rewriting the URL to a `data:`-URI on click. Replace the `data:`-URI with any URI, and there you are. The user will not see the updated link, but it redirects correctly.

Comment: From FB article: Good UX
In order to make for a simpler user experience, we don't want to write these link shim links directly into the site.  If we did, then when anyone hovered over them, their browser would show the Facebook url and not the actual destination.  In order to work around this, we install an onmousedown handler that modifies the link on the fly after the person has clicked it, so their browser hits the link shim first, but they don't see gobbledygook when they mouseover it.  In browsers that don't support javascript, we fall back to simply rewriting these URLs directly.

Comment: No need to rewrite, if you hook into the `click` event in which you do your thing (which should include stopping propagation and returning false to prevent the normal `href` target to be used) you'll get that sort of functionality. That said, bear in mind that you should not use such things to annoy the user, so if you use it to track links clicked or whatever fine, but don't send the user somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an individual link:

```
function $(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
$(link).onclick = function(){ this.href = "http://otherlink.com"; }

<a href="http://example.com" id="link">My Sheisty Link</a>
```

So to get all external links:

```
window.onload = function(){
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(a in links){
  var thisLink = links[a].href.split("/")[2];
  if(thisLink !=== window.location.hostname){
    links[a].href = "http://mainsite.com/link.cgi?u=" + links[a]; }
  // Or you could set onclick like the example above
  // May need to accommodate "www"
}}
```

---

**Edit:**
Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760127/731314) and got a better idea.

```
document.onclick = function (e) {
 e = e ||  window.event;
 var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

if (element.tagName == 'A') {
 var link = element.href.split("/")[2];
  if(link !=== window.location.hostname){
    links[a].href = "http://mainsite.com/link.cgi?u=" + links[a]; }
    return false; // prevent default action and stop event propagation
  }else{ return true; }
}};
```

Comment: Thanks man..!! i've created a nice JS class from your code: https://gist.github.com/2342509

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery then the following will work

```
$('a:link').mousedown(function() { 
  this.href = 'http://my.site.com/link.cgi=' + this.href; 
});
```

Otherwise

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var a = anchors[i];
  if(a.href) {
    a.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      this.href = 'http://my.site.com/link.cgi=' + this.href;
    }, false);
  }
}
```