# What is the best way to make entire web page links non clickable

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, readonly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override default behaviour for link ('a') objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760096/override-default-behaviour-for-link-a-objects-in-javascript)

What is the best way for making entire page links in home page read only (non clickable like `href=#` or `href="javascript:void()"` based on a user action.

I wanted to use only Javascript and CSS to achieve  this.

Comment: For short amount of time until JS executes links will be clickable. Also for browsers with JS disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

with jquery

`$("a").click(function() { return false; });`

vanilla js

```
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].onclick = function () { return false; }
        }
```

Comment: You should provide a vanilla solution too unless they asked for or tagged jQuery.

Comment: Add e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: @Kiyura Yep, I realised this too, as I posted :) Answer updated.

Answer (score 9):

Only css

```
a {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Not guaranteed quite yet, no: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events http://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: Simple and Best Solution.. I checked it.. working fine.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Renjith please never forget the browser compatibility, check on more than one browser (this doesn't work for IE9 which probably isn't old enough yet to disregard)

Comment: It is working in Firefox and chrome.. In IE it doesn't works.. Need to think about a generic solution which is javascript based

Comment: You could always add a Modernizr fallback if you want IE support.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0,len=anchors.length;i<len;i++){
   anchors[i].href = '#';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wonderful solution by [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760127/295264), by using event delegation technique.

```
document.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e ||  window.event;
  var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

  if (element.tagName == 'A') {
    someFunction(element.href);
    return false; // prevent default action and stop event propagation
  }
};
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ufexa)

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
```

Then:

```
for (var i=0; i<links.length; ++i) {
    // disable a link, for instance like this
    links[i].href = "javascript:void()"
}
```

Comment: or `links[i].onclick=function() { return false}`

Comment: @mplungjan, That is not the only way to activate a link.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
$("a").on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault();   
   // anything you want to do on click
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.replaceChild) - it will work in all browsers since NS6/IE6/Chrome1/FX1 or so

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dDEER/)

Plain JS:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

  for(var i=anchors.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML=anchors[i].innerHTML;
    anchors[i].parentNode.replaceChild(span,anchors[i])
    span=null;
  }
}
```

Or my first suggestion in a comment on the page:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var i=anchors.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    anchors[i].onclick=function() { return false }
  }
}
```