# How to maintain String Queries in URL through multiple pages in href

Tags: javascript, html

I have a site that pass discount codes in URL with Query Strings, I want to know how to pass this queries dynamically through navigation when a user clicks in an

```
<a href='mysite.com/page2'>
```

So I want to pass all the current queries to all linked pages dynamically.
It don't necessarily need to be passed through as string queries, if there is a better way to do this...

Comment: If you're just interested in passing data between pages any client side storage would be fine (Session storage, Local Storage, Web SQL, etc)

Comment: Persisting data between pages is more often done using sessions on the server side or local storage in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this much better using client side storage. `localStorage` has good browser support and is easy to implement. Saving a value:

```
localStorage.setItem( "key", "some value" );
```

Retrieving `key`:

```
var retrievedString = localStorage.getItem( "key" );
```

The saved values will persist between page navigations, and even after the session ends. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

---

But as far as passing current querys through links, you can override the default behaviour of all `<a>` tags, and instead run a function that gets the `href` of the link and the query section of the current page's url, merges them together into a new url and then navigates there. (modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760096/override-default-behaviour-for-link-a-objects-in-javascript))

```
document.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e ||  window.event;
    var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (element.tagName == 'A') {
        var q = location.href; 
        window.location.href = element.href + q.substring( q.indexOf( "?" ) );
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is a good way to do this! But for my problem I saw that window.sessionStorage is better than localStorage. Thank you!