# Javascript interrupt normal behavior on link click momentarily

Tags: javascript

I want to do something before my page unloads so I'm trying to interrupt normal behaviour momentarily. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760096/override-default-behaviour-for-link-a-objects-in-javascript) but it doesn't seem to work:

```
document.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

  if (element.tagName == `a`) {
    document.body.classList.remove(`ready`);
    document.body.classList.add(`leaving`);

    setTimeout(function () {
      return true; // return false = prevent default action and stop event propagation
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

0.5s is the time I need to display a short css animation before leaving the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
document.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (element.tagName == `A`) {     // !uppercased
    e.preventDefault();             // prevent default anchor behavior
    var goTo = element.href;        // store target url

    document.body.classList.remove(`ready`);
    document.body.classList.add(`leaving`);

    setTimeout(function () {
      window.location = goTo;        // navigate to destination
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but preventDefault doesn't seem to work as even when I remove the window.location live it still loads the next page.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I changed tagName == `A` from the original code to tagName == `a`, that's what stopped your code from working but now it's all good :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't pay attention on it:) Updated the answer