# Inserting JWT Token in outgoing href clicks

Tags: javascript, jwt, angular-http-interceptors

I have a specific requirement where I can NOT use Angular but only use usual Javascript. When user clicks a href link, javascript should capture the click and add JWT token in http header.

I followed suggestion in below link but it does not solve my issue:

[Override default behaviour for link ('a') objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760096/override-default-behaviour-for-link-a-objects-in-javascript)

It is possible at all to capture the href clicks and add JWT token to the request.

Another additional questions - How the browser send the href clicks to the server? I know in case of form submission, I can use XHR post to do it. But what mechanism the browser usees to send href clicks to the server.

Comment: If it's just a navigation to another page you cannot manage it's headers: only url is what you can change.

Comment: Thanks....

When I navigate to another page in the browser ( i.e. from Home, I click About Us link), would not the browser send http request to server to load the new page? Can I not capture that browser to server message and change my headers. I saw below link in web: 


https://igoro.com/archive/what-really-happens-when-you-navigate-to-a-url/

Comment: Browser fully manages the process of navigating to another page, you can only set the url. I don't see anything relevant on that link.