# Html is there a way to send a concat from desktop to mobile phone?

Tags: javascript, html

On my website i have button that triggers SMS to my phone. And it works fine for mobile users.

```
<a href="sms:+**********?body=Describe your question" class="default-btn-sized default-btn mobile-option">Start Chat</a>
```

But what can i do with desktop users? Is there a way to send this contact to their phone? or what is common approach about that?

Comment: "Is there a way to send this contact to their phone?" Not really. If you click on it there are a few applications on a computer that can handle them links (Skype I think) but _normal_ practice would be to just include a phone number in plain text.

Comment: You want a desktop based browser to open a text-message on their phone?!

Comment: @freefaller kinda, i know i can send map coordinates from desktop to my phone, but i guess i has to do with Google map service and shared email. Just wonder if similar possible in my case

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like an [SMPP protocal](https://smpp.org/) to send sms via a server side script like PHP. Along with some tricks...

Example PHP SMPP lib Code: https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp

Things to do:

- Find an smpp provider. Possible free one ->
  https://smppex.rubybox.ru/
- Detect if the browser is desktop or phone:

```js
var pathname = $(location).attr("pathname");
if (
  /android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|nokia|opera mini|opera mobi|skyfire|maemo|windows phone|palm|iemobile|symbian|symbianos|fennec/i.test(
    navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
  )
) { /* mobile code */ } else { /* desktop code */ }
```

- Then dverride the default behaviour of the link to a click event in Javascript: [Override default behaviour for link ('a') objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760096/override-default-behaviour-for-link-a-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Desktop does not support sending SMS messages.
Unless you have an application to send messages on your device, if you have an application, you will need to open the application, you can check this link
[how to start up a desktop application in client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265717/how-to-start-up-a-desktop-application-in-client-side)
But there are other ways such as sending an email and you can do this

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">start email</a>
```

and u can start chat in whatsapp like this :

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=*****">start whatsapp</a>
```